# What is the Order of Growth of sorting M elements N times, where M can differ?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have a situation where I am looping N times to sort M elements using merge sort. M can differ, i.e., depend on which N iterations we're at.

I came up with `O(nmlog(m))`, where `n` is the number of outer elements, and `m` is the average number of inner elements, but this doesn't sound right.

Comment: It's sum(i=1 to N of m_i * log(m_i)). Unless you can say something about the m_i you're stuck there.

Comment: If the lists you are sorting are not the same length, then it does not make sense to describe this as "sorting M elements N times" - just say you are sorting N lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can say is `n` times the average of `mi log(mi)`, for which there is no simple formula. You could express this as `nm*log(m*)` where `m*` is the value that solves `m*log(m*) = avg(mi log(mi))`, but this is even less tractable.

As the function `x log(x)` is upward concave, `m*` will be somewhat *above* `M:= avg(mi)`.

If the coefficient of variation of the `mi` is small, you can use the decomposition `mi = M + δi` and take the average of `(M + δi) (log M + log(1 + δi/M)) ~ (M + δi) (log M + δi/M)`. By averaging, the terms in `δi` cancel out and what remains is the average of `M log M + δi²/M = M log M + σ²/M`. Hence `O(NM log M + Nσ²/M)`, which is `O(NM log M)`.